# Solving $(\sqrt{xy}-x)\,dy+y\, dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve the initial value problem
$$
(\sqrt{xy}-x)\,dy+y\, dx=0
$$
$$
y(1)=0
$$
I have done the following: $y=xu$, $dy= u\,dx+x\, du$,
$$
(\sqrt{x^2u}-x)(u\,dx+x\, du)+xu\, dx=0
$$
$$
(|x|\sqrt{u}-x)x\, du+|x|u\sqrt{u}\,dx=0
$$
($|x|=x$ because the initial value $x=1$)
$$
(\sqrt{u}-1)x^2\, du=-xu\sqrt{u}\,dx
$$
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{u}-1)\, du}{u\sqrt{u}}=-\frac{dx}{x}
$$
$$
\int\left( \frac1{u}-\frac1{u\sqrt{u}} \right)\, du=-\int\frac{dx}{x}
$$
$$
\ln |u|+\frac2{\sqrt{u}}+\ln |x|= C
$$
$$
\ln |ux|+\frac2{\sqrt{u}}= C
$$
$$
\ln |y|+\frac2{\sqrt{y/x}}= C
$$
I don't know how to obtain an initial value problem solution from this. I can't take a logarithm of zero and I can't divide by zero. Maybe I was wrong somewhere?

Upd. I was hinted to introduce a function $x(y)$ and solve the equation for it, but I obtained an equally useless result
$$
\sqrt{x}=-\frac{y^2\sqrt{y}}4+C\sqrt{y}
$$

Comment: are you sure about the initial conditions??

Comment: @Learning Absolutely. I checked it several times

Comment: When using separation of variables on $u' = f(x)g(u)$, you need to exclude constant solutions $u$ with $g(u) = 0$ *before* dividing by $g(u)$!

Comment: @Christoph Wow! You are right! And the solution is $y(x)=0$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{u}-1)\, du}{u\sqrt{u}}=-\frac{dx}{x}
$$
takes place a division by zero. So we should check the solution $u=0$
or $y/x=0$, i.e. $y=0$. It is indeed  a solution and it satisfies the initial conditions! So the answer is $y(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Mate,Your procedure and solution is totally right .
But given initial condition is wrong ,since the solution curve $$\ln |y|+\frac2{\sqrt{y/x}}= C$$
Doesn't pass through point $(1,0)$
That's why are not getting any finite $C$ here..

Comment: There shouldnt be $2ln|y|$.

Comment: That's ok with the initial conditions. I just insensibly divided by zero

Answer (score 0):

The given ODE is homogeneous
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x-\sqrt{xy}}.$$
Use $y=vx \implies y'=v+xv'$
We get $$\int \left(\frac{1}{v\sqrt{v}}-\frac{1}{v} \right)=\int \frac{dx}{x} \implies
\frac{-2}{\sqrt{v}}=\ln v-\ln Cx \implies -2\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}\ln{Cy}$$

Comment: This does not help because the initial value $y=0$